# facebook ,google notification for web apps

Tags: facebook

Currently I am working on a web app which has authorizations for user's facebook and google account to get some data from these sites.
I used:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {    
        user_id = response.authResponse.userID;
        accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
    }
    else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
        // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
        // but has not authenticated your app
    }
    else {
        // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
    }
});
```

to get oauth token.

Now I want whenever a user logs in to his facebook or google acount. I get notification at my web application that this user has been logged in.

Comment: Do you mean you get notified whenever they log in to your site using Facebook/Google or that whenever they log in to Facebook.com you get notified?

Comment: whenever they login to facebook or google.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make an application that will notify you every time someone logs in to Facebook/Google+. You can, however, be told whenever they use your application or visit your website that uses their respective social APIs. Doing this is fairly trivial and just involves firing off an email whenever you do authentication/login of the person to your application.